# Is Jasypt secure enough to use?

Tags: jasypt

We are using Jasypt in one of our Spring based project to encrypt our database properties. As per Jasypt documentation we need to make algorith and password (secret) entry in our application context.

```
 <bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration"
    class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
   <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
   <property name="passwordEnvName" value="secret" />
 </bean>
  <bean id="configurationEncryptor"
     class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
   <property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
 </bean>
  <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
     class="org.jasypt.spring.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
    <property name="location" value="classpath*:*.properties" />
 </bean>
```

If we do that, any one can easily decrypt our properties by decrypt property provided by Jasypt only. For example

```
 sh decrypt.sh input=pYmd0m1m2nEAGIeTtfdfdfdl/e3W49e password=sdsdfsf algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
```

So how we can ensure the security of our property files.